# Understanding くらいですから

Tags: reading-comprehension

From [痴人の愛](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001383/files/58093_62049.html),

> 「河合譲治君」と云えば、会社の中でも「君子」という評判があったくらいですから。

I am uncertain about くらいですから in this sentence. This sentence serves as a reason for what? Doing well in the company?

> 何の不平も不満もなく日々の仕事を勤めている

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reason for

先ず模範的なサラリー・マン、[...]当時の私は大方そんな風だったでしょう。

I was a 模範的なサラリーマン to the extent that 会社の中でも君子という評判があった.